# Rails.application.config vs Rails.configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any difference between using `Rails.application.config` vs `Rails.configuration` when doing [custom configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Other than character count, there is no difference between the two methods. They both end up pointing to the same configuration object:

- [Rails.configuration](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3e36db4406beea32772b1db1e9a16cc1e8aea14c/railties/lib/rails.rb#L43-L45)
- [Rails.application.config](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3e36db4406beea32772b1db1e9a16cc1e8aea14c/railties/lib/rails.rb#L36-L38)